# How to change Inkscape icons in KDE?

Tags: inkscape

How can I get back the old Inkscape icons?

I tried:    `sudo cp /usr/share/inkscape/icons/icons.svg ~/.config/inkscape/icons/` but it still doesn't work.

[image]

*System: Ubuntu 16.04*

edit:

Using version *0.92.2*
(Have same problem with version *0.91x* and *0.92.0* too btw)

edit 2:
Am Using KDE

**Update** 
Ok, the problem was KDE, changing gnome applications setting GTK  solved the problem by choosing gnome for icons.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64403/discussion-on-question-by-asme-just-how-to-change-inkscape-icons-in-kde).